# Theoretical justification behind assuming that the data is locally uniformly distributed, as seem to be used by manifold learning community

Tags: machine-learning, dimensionality-reduction, uniform-distribution, unsupervised-learning, manifold-learning

In at least three or more papers I've been studying that introduced novel algorithms for the estimation of intrinsic dimensionality (ID) *based on nearest neighborhood (NN) techniques*, I observed that **they're assuming that the data is locally uniformly distributed, and I can't seem to understand why. But before going to my question, let me cite some links, and point out where exactly they used this assumption:**

(1) [This Nature paper from 2018](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1803/1803.06992.pdf) mentions it on Page 2.

(2) [This well-cited 2012 paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F978-3-642-23783-6_24.pdf) mentions on P.3, Sec 3.1 that "we firstly consider the unit hypersphere $B_d(0_d, 1) \subset \mathbb{R}^d$
centered in the origin and uniformly sampled; furthermore, we assume $\psi$ to be
the identity map. Considering $k$ points $\{z_i\}_{1 \le i \le k}$
$i=1$ uniformly drawn from $B_d(0_d, 1)$",
our aim is to find the pdf related to the minimum distance between the $k$ points
and the hypersphere center $0_d$." *Although they made an attempt to relax the locally uniformity part later in Theorem 1, I'm not sure that establishes a proof of the fact that it's okay to assume that the data is locally uniformly distributed*.

(3) [This recent 2020 paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.11739.pdf) states on Page 2 that: "...most of the local ID estimators use
pairwise distances (relationship between two points) or angular
information (relationship between three points)  whereas others take into account the volume of a simplex 
... **The common approach is to assume
local distributions of data points are close to a uniformly
sampled unit $n$-ball $B_n$ or their scaled vectors to a uniformly
sampled unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$.**

**My take on this, but not sure:**  (a) I guess one rationale behind this assumption could be that the PDF is continuous, so almost constant on a small enough neighborhood, but the problems with this is: (1) one needs to state how much the PDF deviates from the constant in that neighborhood, so some kind of explicit control/bound on the deviation from being a constant is achieved, and (2) even if we assume that PDF $f$ is constant locally, say $f \equiv c,$ on a neighborhood $U,$ this does ***not*** guarantee that $c$ satisfies , $c=\frac{1}{vol(U)}$, so that $\int_{U}f(x)dx^1\dots dx^n=1$. I mean $c$ does not have to be equal to $\frac{1}{vol(U)}$  in the first place.

(b) If we assume that the data were represented in lower dimension $d$ by a normal random vector $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \Sigma)$ in $\mathbb{R}^d,$ then after scaling and re-positioning we can assume that $Z:=\Sigma^{1/2}(X - \mu) \sim \mathcal{N}(0_d, I_d)$. And only if the intrinsic dimensionality $d$ is also large, $\mathcal{N}(0_d, I_d) \approx Unif(\sqrt{d}\mathbb{S}^{d-1})$ thanks to the concentration of $||Z||_2$ near $\sqrt{d}$. *But this is as bad as assuming that the data were normally distributed- so not sure it's a good assumption.*

**So I don't see why this assumtion of locally uniformity is justified? Help appreciated :)**